# Can we use Named Credentials with this Weird API?

Tags: api, callout, url, externalid, namedcredentials

In order to do something, we need to make call outs to an external server where the URL takes the format:

```
http://www.example.com/path/{external_id}/doSomething?api-key={api-key}
```

The `external-id` would be specific to and stored in individual records and swapped out for each call.

The `api-key` would normally be a "fixed" value, although it might (of course) occasionally be updated.  And our production org would call a different server instance than our sandboxes (which may or may not share the test server) and (of course) this key would be different than production.

(In the medium/long run, we might change the API since putting the key in the URL doesn't seem like a great idea... but til then...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a custom authentication scheme negates part of the benefit of using Named Credentials, but you can still do so. Assuming the endpoint is:

```
http://www.example.com/path/
```

Your code would look like:

```
req.setEndpoint(
  String.format('callout:example/{0}/doSomething?api-key={1}',
    new String[] { externalId, apiKey }));
```

Ideally, you should move to OAuth or even Basic Authentication, which reduces your complexity to just:

```
req.setEndpoint(
  String.format('callout:example/{0}/doSomething',
    new String[] { externalId }));
```

And eliminates the need to store the API key in a custom setting/custom label/etc since it will be managed by the system, which is part of the benefit of using Named Credentials.

Comment: How do add the API key from the named credential password?